# Use SSL Certificate on local ServiceFabric httpGatewayEndpointPort

Tags: ssl, service-fabric-on-premises

We have a Local Service Fabric Cluster running. We are using Windows Security to control who can administer the cluster.

When connecting to the Gateway Endpoint to use the configuration manager, we are currently connecting over HTTP, but we'd like to connect over HTTPS.

We have added an SSL Certificate that we use for connecting to the reverse proxy, and we'd like to use that same certificate to connect to the Gateway Endpoint.

I can see in the generated config on the cluster that the HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint port is using https, which I think turned on because I set the "ReverseProxyCertificate" setting.

```
<NodeType Name="NodeType0">
  <Endpoints>
    <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
    <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19002" />
    <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19001" />
    <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
    <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="https" />
    <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19003" />
    <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="20001" EndPort="20031" />
    <EphemeralEndpoints StartPort="49152" EndPort="65535" />
  </Endpoints>
  <PlacementProperties>
    <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType0" />
  </PlacementProperties>
</NodeType>
```

How can I make the HttpGatewayEndpoint have Protocol="https" instead of "http"?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have exactly the same requirement.

Comment: Nope, still running on http. I'd love an answer if you find one though.